# Como indexar subgrupos em R

Tags: r

O que preciso é indexar subgrupos dentro de um grupo e que o R me traga um resultado específico, linha a linha, dependendo do subgrupo.

Primeiro preciso agrupar os dados por processo. Isso eu consegui com `group_by`:

```r
dados <- data.frame(processos = c("123","123","123","abc","abc","xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz"),
                    situacao = c("a","b","c","c","b","c","a","a","b"),
                    resultado = c("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"))

dados <- 
  dados %>% 
  group_by(processos)
```

Preciso que o R verifique na coluna `situacao` quando o `b` aparece. Em seguida, que coloque todas as linhas do grupo processo com 1 e todas as linhas do grupo `b` como 2. Preciso que ele faça esse preenchimento processo a processo.

Detalhe que os grupos (processos) possuem tamanhos diferentes. O resultado esperado ficaria assim:

```r
dados
         processos situacao resultado
    1       123        a         1
    2       123        b         2
    3       123        c         1
    4       abc        c         1
    5       abc        b         2
    6       xyz        c         1
    7       xyz        a         1
    8       xyz        a         1
    9       xyz        b         2
```

Já tentei `aggregate`, `mutate`, `if_else`, `if`, mas todos sem qualquer sucesso.

Answer (score 2):

Basta usar `mutate` combinado com `if_else`. Se a coluna `situacao` for igual a `b`, resultado recebe 2. Caso contrário, recebe 1. Sequer é preciso agrupar os dados, pois a informação dos processos não é utilizada em nenhum momento.

```r
library(dplyr)

dados %>%
  mutate(resultado = if_else(situacao == "b", 2, 1))
#>   processos situacao resultado
#> 1       123        a         1
#> 2       123        b         2
#> 3       123        c         1
#> 4       abc        c         1
#> 5       abc        b         2
#> 6       xyz        c         1
#> 7       xyz        a         1
#> 8       xyz        a         1
#> 9       xyz        b         2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Usa o truquezinho do `cumsum`, que aí adiciona 1 quando aparece um b no grupo.

```r
dados <- data.frame(processos = c("123","123","123","abc","abc","xyz","xyz","xyz","xyz"),
                    situacao = c("a","b","c","c","b","c","a","a","b"),
                    resultado = c("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"))
library(dplyr)

dados <- 
  dados %>% 
  group_by(processos) %>% 
  mutate(resultado = cumsum(situacao == "b") + 1)

dados
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   processos [3]
#>   processos situacao resultado
#>   <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 123       a                1
#> 2 123       b                2
#> 3 123       c                2
#> 4 abc       c                1
#> 5 abc       b                2
#> 6 xyz       c                1
#> 7 xyz       a                1
#> 8 xyz       a                1
#> 9 xyz       b                2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Algo tão simples, mas que me bateu muito! haha, Conhecimento é tudo mesmo!

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se o resultado do processamento é igual para todos os grupos, então não depende do grupo.
Esta solução utiliza o facto de uma condição lógica corresponder aos inteiros `0/1`. Basta então somar 1 aos valores de igualdade a `"b"`.

```
library(dplyr)

dados %>% mutate(resultado = (situacao == "b") + 1L)
#  processos situacao resultado
#1       123        a         1
#2       123        b         2
#3       123        c         1
#4       abc        c         1
#5       abc        b         2
#6       xyz        c         1
#7       xyz        a         1
#8       xyz        a         1
#9       xyz        b         2
```

---

### Edição

Uma resposta do AP que deveria de facto ser um comentário às respostas já existentes é a seguinte:

> Eu tentei desse jeito, mas ele só traz o resultado 2 na linha onde o
> "b" aparece. Eu preciso mesmo é que antes do "b" todas as linhas sejam
> 1 e do "b" para frente todas as linhas sejam 2. Quando mudar o
> processo o indicador deve voltar para 1.
>
> Assim, no primeiro processo o resultado seria 1,2,2 e na linha 4 o
> marcador volta para 1.

Depois desta resposta, passa a ser evidente que se deve agrupar por `processos` e o código certo será o seguinte. (Entretanto já há uma [resposta igual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/510002/82237), do usuário [@Jorge Mendes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/150167/jorge-mendes).)

```
dados %>% 
  group_by(processos) %>% 
  mutate(resultado = cumsum(situacao == "b") + 1L)
## A tibble: 9 x 3
## Groups:   processos [3]
#  processos situacao resultado
#  <chr>     <chr>        <int>
#1 123       a                1
#2 123       b                2
#3 123       c                2
#4 abc       c                1
#5 abc       b                2
#6 xyz       c                1
#7 xyz       a                1
#8 xyz       a                1
#9 xyz       b                2
```